# Make SVG path take full width and height of screen

Tags: html, css, svg

I have an inline SVG path that animates a dash to look like the snake game. Now my question is how to get this path to take up the full width and height of the screen and act responsive if the screen goes smaller or bigger.

HTML

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 659 522" enable-background="new 0 0 659 522" xml:space="preserve">
    <path class="path" width="100%" height="100%" fill="none" stroke="#00ff00" stroke-width="5" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M656.5,2.5v517H2.5V2.5H656.5z"
    stroke-dasharray="2042 300"
    stroke-dashoffset="2342" />
</svg>
```

CSS

```
.path {
    animation: dash 10s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes dash {
    to {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    }
}
```

Here is a fiddle with the code I have.

http://jsfiddle.net/c3ar6e5o/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to tell the SVG not to maintain its aspect ratio with `preserveAspectRatio="none"` in the SVG code..then it's just CSS.

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/c3ar6e5o/2/)

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
svg {
  display: block;
}
.path {
  animation: dash 10s linear infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes dash {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 659 522" enable-background="new 0 0 659 522" xml:space="preserve" preserveAspectRatio="none">
  <path class="path" width="100%" height="100%" fill="none" stroke="#00ff00" stroke-width="5" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M656.5,2.5v517H2.5V2.5H656.5z" stroke-dasharray="2042 300" stroke-dashoffset="2342" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks this seems to help, the only problem is that the stroke seems to be stretched.

Comment: In the Snippet yes...but check the JSfiddle (now corrected link)

Comment: In the fiddle it seems to be stretched as well for me

Comment: Hmmm...looks Ok in Chrome to me.

Comment: is there a fix to not stretch the stroke?

Comment: @JacobRaccuia Setting `vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"` property on the path should help you remove the stretch. (JSfiddle updated)