# change path width to 100% of svg container

Tags: html, css, svg

I have an svg background image but path is not 100% of svg width. I have tried change preserveaspectratio as well but did not work.

```html
<svg x="0" y="0" viewBox="0 0 2227 1601" >
<path  d="M2166.88,40.32V1441.8l-323.83-195.25a347.4,347.4,0,0,0-352.44-3.72l-5.15,3-397.67,228.46a347.4,347.4,0,0,1-360.61-8.79L61,1038.23V40.32Z"/></svg>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make SVG path take full width and height of screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32611745/make-svg-path-take-full-width-and-height-of-screen)

Comment: You need to use this `viewBox="viewBox="61 40 2105 1482"`. In order to know what value to use you need to get the bounding box of the path with [getBBox()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGGraphicsElement/getBBox) and use those values

Comment: @enxaneta it moved to top left corner but width is still not 100%

Comment: @SimoneRossaini its not working in my case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I've commented you need to change the value of the viewBox attribute.
In the next example the svg element has overflow:visible so that you can see that there is no overflow.

```js
let bb = thePath.getBBox();

theSVG.setAttributeNS(null,"viewBox", `${bb.x} ${bb.y} ${bb.width} ${bb.height}`)
```

```css
svg{border:solid; width:200px; overflow:visible}
```

```html
<svg id="theSVG" x="0" y="0" viewBox="0 0 2227 1601" >
<path id="thePath"  d="M2166.88,40.32V1441.8l-323.83-195.25a347.4,347.4,0,0,0-352.44-3.72l-5.15,3-397.67,228.46a347.4,347.4,0,0,1-360.61-8.79L61,1038.23V40.32Z"/>
</svg>
```

If you need to add some sort of white space around the path you can do this:

```
theSVG.setAttributeNS(null,"viewBox", `${bb.x - padding} ${bb.y - padding} ${bb.width + 2* padding} ${bb.height + 2 * padding}`)
```

```js
let bb = thePath.getBBox();
let padding = 30;

theSVG.setAttributeNS(null,"viewBox", `${bb.x - padding} ${bb.y - padding} ${bb.width + 2* padding} ${bb.height + 2 * padding}`)
```

```css
svg{border:solid; width:200px; overflow:visible}
```

```html
<svg id="theSVG" x="0" y="0" viewBox="0 0 2227 1601" >
<path id="thePath"  d="M2166.88,40.32V1441.8l-323.83-195.25a347.4,347.4,0,0,0-352.44-3.72l-5.15,3-397.67,228.46a347.4,347.4,0,0,1-360.61-8.79L61,1038.23V40.32Z"/>
</svg>
```