# Fitting whole svg in a resizable div

Tags: html, css, svg, resize

I have been trying for a while to find a solution for this but it's worthless since I don't know svg and html that well :(
Here is the behavior: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHuJH.gif
I would like the svg to always fit inside the resizable div. It is working for height but not for width...
Here is the html:

```html
<div id="parent" style="height:200px; width:200px;"><!--!-->
<div style="height:100%; width:100%; overflow:hidden"><!--!-->
<!--!-->            <div style="text-align:center;display:flex; height:inherit"><!--!-->
                <!--!--><svg id="svgzonecorrelogram" style="height:100%;width:100%" viewBox="0 0 500 600" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet"><text x="221" y="221" fill="grey" font-size="18" font-weight="bold" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="middle">1<title>1</title></text><text x="221" y="463" fill="#383838" font-size="18" font-weight="bold" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="middle">1,00</text><circle cx="463" cy="221" r="116" fill="#000080"></circle><text x="463" y="463" fill="grey" font-size="18" font-weight="bold" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="middle">1<title>1</title></text><rect x="100" y="100" width="242" height="242" style="stroke: lightgray;stroke - width: 1px; fill: transparent; "><title>1,00</title></rect><rect x="342" y="100" width="242" height="242" style="stroke: lightgray;stroke - width: 1px; fill: transparent; "><title>1,00</title></rect><rect x="100" y="342" width="242" height="242" style="stroke: lightgray;stroke - width: 1px; fill: transparent; "><title>1,00</title></rect><rect x="342" y="342" width="242" height="242" style="stroke: lightgray;stroke - width: 1px; fill: transparent; "><title>1,00</title></rect><linearGradient id="lingrad" x1="0" x2="0" y1="0" y2="1"><stop offset="0%" stop-color="Navy"></stop><stop offset="50%" stop-color="#E5E4E2"></stop><stop offset="100%" stop-color="FireBrick"></stop></linearGradient><rect x="605" y="100" width="20" height="485" style="stroke: lightgray;stroke - width: 1px;" fill="url(#lingrad)"></rect><text x="635" y="105" font-size="22">1.0</text><text x="635" y="342" font-size="22">0.0</text><text x="630" y="590" font-size="22">-1.0</text><text x="95" y="221" fill="grey" font-size="18" font-weight="bold" text-anchor="end" dominant-baseline="middle">...fgdfgdfg<title>test1fffffffffffffffffffffffgdfgdfgdfgdfg</title></text><text x="221" y="95" fill="grey" font-size="18" font-weight="bold" text-anchor="end" dominant-baseline="middle" transform="rotate(90,221,97)">...fgdfgdfg<title>test1fffffffffffffffffffffffgdfgdfgdfgdfg</title></text><text x="95" y="463" fill="grey" font-size="18" font-weight="bold" text-anchor="end" dominant-baseline="middle">test2<title>test2</title></text><text x="463" y="95" fill="grey" font-size="18" font-weight="bold" text-anchor="end" dominant-baseline="middle" transform="rotate(90,463,97)">test2<title>test2</title></text></svg><!--!-->
            </div><!--!-->
        </div>
                </div>
```

I would like to have my complete svg with correct proportions for any width and height of the "parent" div

Thanks in advance

Rihen

Comment: you need to give the parent div a different size like 90vw. Now your parent have height:200px; width:200px; and it's not resizable. For the SVG I've changed the viewBox to `viewBox="16 18 650 580"` Please take a look at this answer to see how to calculate the value of the viewBox: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62693472/change-path-width-to-100-of-svg-container/62694406#62694406

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, **you can't make your element fit the window both horizontally and vertically** since this is not a perfect shape to fit the window, so you just have to choose between horizontal and vertical fitness. As long as you want to resize your element with window resize you should consider it to fit horizontally by its width. **To make this work you won't need any parent wrapper with `width` and `height` specification and you should also remove the `width` and `height` attribute from your `svg` element also since it will automatically fill the available space** *(It will fill the parent container which in this case it is `window` itself)*. So you just need to modify your [`viewBox`](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwi06fy46bDqAhUGaBoKHdkDAhMQFjAAegQIAxAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FSVG%2FAttribute%2FviewBox&usg=AOvVaw0oz6_scdW4KXQKXQEBp3gg) attribute since `viewBox` stands for `min-x`, `min-y`, `width` and `height` you just have to know your exact image size and you can ignore the first two attribute.

Here how it looks like at the end:

```html
<svg id="svgzonecorrelogram" viewBox="0 0 670 610" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet"><text x="221" y="221" fill="grey" font-size="18" font-weight="bold" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="middle">1<title>1</title></text><text x="221" y="463" fill="#383838" font-size="18" font-weight="bold" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="middle">1,00</text>
  <circle cx="463" cy="221" r="116" fill="#000080"></circle><text x="463" y="463" fill="grey" font-size="18" font-weight="bold" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="middle">1<title>1</title></text>
  <rect x="100" y="100" width="242" height="242" style="stroke: lightgray;stroke - width: 1px; fill: transparent; ">
    <title>1,00</title>
  </rect>
  <rect x="342" y="100" width="242" height="242" style="stroke: lightgray;stroke - width: 1px; fill: transparent; ">
    <title>1,00</title>
  </rect>
  <rect x="100" y="342" width="242" height="242" style="stroke: lightgray;stroke - width: 1px; fill: transparent; ">
    <title>1,00</title>
  </rect>
  <rect x="342" y="342" width="242" height="242" style="stroke: lightgray;stroke - width: 1px; fill: transparent; ">
    <title>1,00</title>
  </rect>
  <linearGradient id="lingrad" x1="0" x2="0" y1="0" y2="1">
    <stop offset="0%" stop-color="Navy"></stop>
    <stop offset="50%" stop-color="#E5E4E2"></stop>
    <stop offset="100%" stop-color="FireBrick"></stop>
  </linearGradient>
  <rect x="605" y="100" width="20" height="485" style="stroke: lightgray;stroke - width: 1px;" fill="url(#lingrad)"></rect><text x="635" y="105" font-size="22">1.0</text><text x="635" y="342" font-size="22">0.0</text><text x="630" y="590" font-size="22">-1.0</text><text x="95" y="221" fill="grey" font-size="18" font-weight="bold" text-anchor="end" dominant-baseline="middle">...fgdfgdfg<title>test1fffffffffffffffffffffffgdfgdfgdfgdfg</title></text><text x="221" y="95" fill="grey" font-size="18" font-weight="bold" text-anchor="end" dominant-baseline="middle" transform="rotate(90,221,97)">...fgdfgdfg<title>test1fffffffffffffffffffffffgdfgdfgdfgdfg</title></text><text x="95" y="463" fill="grey" font-size="18" font-weight="bold" text-anchor="end" dominant-baseline="middle">test2<title>test2</title></text><text x="463" y="95" fill="grey" font-size="18" font-weight="bold" text-anchor="end" dominant-baseline="middle" transform="rotate(90,463,97)">test2<title>test2</title></text>
</svg>
```